# Registration and Login form having different styles

Tags: forms, users

I'm trying to style the login and registration form in different styles in my drupal 7 website. By default they share the same styles. Is there any way to change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your theme's template.php file:

```
function MYTHEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    $form['#attached']['css'][] = path_to_theme() . '/css/user-register-form.css';
  }
  elseif ($form_id == 'user_login') {
    $form['#attached']['css'][] = path_to_theme() . '/css/user-login.css';
  }
}
```

And then define your two css files.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the [themekey module](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey):

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching
>   rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current
>   path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other
>   properties. It can also be easily extended to support additional
>   properties exposed by other modules.